# Firebase createUser then setCustomUserClaims in the Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a user, set the custom claims and then set data into `firestore` using cloud functions. Below code works fine with `firebase serve` just wanted some feedback from firebase community. Since I'm nesting `then()` it gives warnings too. Is there any better way?

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/register', (request, response) => {
  const data = request.body;

  firebase.auth().createUser(data)
    .then((userRecord) => {

      firebase.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, { admin: true }
        .then(() => {
          db.collection("users").doc().set(data)
            .then((payload) => {
              return response.send({ success: 'success' });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              return response.send(error);
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return response.send(error);
        })

      return response.send(successMsg);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return response.send(error);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would chain the promises as follows:

```
app.post('/register', (request, response) => {
  const data = request.body;

  admin.auth().createUser(data)
  .then((userRecord) => {
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, { admin: true });
  })
  .then(() => {
      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc().set(data);
  })      
  .then(() => {
      response.send({ success: 'success' });   //Don't need to return here, since it is an HTTPS Cloud Function, just send the response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      response.status(500).send(error);
  })
})
```

Note that I have changed `firebase.auth().createUser(data)` to `admin.auth().createUser(data)` since the `createUser()` method belongs to the Admin SDK, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#createUser. I did the same with `admin.firestore()`.

You can keep the `firebase` variable/constant name but then you need to declare the Admin SDK as

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
```

Comment: thanks, great job! One weird thing was ESLint threw an error on success, so I had to use `return response.send({ success: 'success' })` weird